# my console app in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

my bat file:

```
myprogram.exe >> c:\temp\log.txt
```

my program is getting a null reference error but not sure why the message is not getting logged in log file. When i run manually in command window i see the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also have your batch file output stderr to a log file as well. Try

`myprogram.exe >> c:\temp\log.txt 2> c:\temp\err.txt`

Comment: Any chance of getting a timestamp for each time error occurs, if not, no biggie.

Answer (score 6):

Because `>>` is Standard Output and your error goes to Standard Error.

You can pass the error into Standard Output if you catch it and write it to `Console`